# loading and running an aggregation in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I've coded an aggregation I want to run on a collection in the mongo shell. If I paste it directly into the shell, I have to do it line by line which is tedious and slow, especially when it doesn't work and I have to do it over. Therefore, I put it in a .js document and loaded it like this `load("myaggregation.js")` but that only returns `true` if the code is valid. How do I run the aggregation after loading it? I can't find any documentation about this.  Do I have to use the nodejs driver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your aggregation code in a function:

```
function my_aggregate() { 
    return db.foo.aggregate( [ ... ] );
}
```

and store that in your `.js` file.

Then run `load` to load it. You can also pass the filename on the commandline using the `--shell` commandline flag which will start the interactive shell after running any specified `.js` files.

Once the file is run your new function will be available to execute. Simply type

```
my_aggregate()
```

**Update** You do have to use an explicit `return` which I failed to mention. So in your case you would want something like:

```
function my_aggregate() {
    return db.zips.aggregate([{ $match: { state: { $in: [ "CA", "NY" ] } }},{ $group:{ _id : {  "state" : "$state","city" : "$city" }, pop : { $sum: "$pop"}}},{ $match: {  pop: { $gt: 25000 } }},{$group:{ _id : {   "city" : "$city"}, pop : { $avg: "$pop"}}}]);
}
```

Comment: I have an working aggregation which I wrapped in function my_aggregate(){ } and stored in a file called function.js. From within mongo shell, I did load("function.js") and it output `true`, and I ran `my_aggregate()` and it did nothing. Did I miss something in your answer?  thanks if you can clarify

Comment: What are you doing with the aggregation result in your function? What is the `return` value?

Comment: Have a look, do I have to explicitly declare a return value? if I run the aggregation 'as is' in the console (without the function) i don't know to declare a return value, but it's different this way?  http://pastebin.com/wWQHUbpW

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil Yes, you have to explicitly use `return` in your function. When typing in the shell, expressions are evaluated inside a REPL which automatically displays the return value. Your function returns nothing, so it's just evaluated as an expression. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: @friedo maybe reference [load](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/) function? Your answer helped me, thanks, but it was not fully clear on how to use `load` just from your explanation

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/?

Something like: mongo localhost:27017/test myjsfile.js

It also says that "You can execute a .js file from within the mongo shell, using the load() function".

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer but I found a nice way to handle this:

Create a js file containing your aggregate query:

```
use blog; 

db.posts.aggregate([  
    ... my query ... 
]);
```

then you can simply cat and pipe the file to mongo client:

```
cat myfile.js | mongo
```

Answer (score 1):

script.js file content:

```
aggrQuery = db.foo.aggregate([

    {$group: {_id: '$bar', pop: {$max: '$buz'}}}
])
```

in the mongo shell:

```
> load('/file/location/script.js');
true
>aggrQuery
here will be output
```